# How I can get the information of new instance launch in AWS by API calling in bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, amazon-web-services

The idea:

I am building some terminal interface for my team and I wanted to use aws api inside that bash script to let me know when a new instances get launched.So It can automatically added to a flat file I am calling inside script.

Which in turn reflect in the specific menu .

Like this :

1) Jenkin_Server 2) Nagios_Server 3) PRod_server 4) UAT_Server

The interface has been desinged and tested by bash script.Pretty ordinary bash "select" options.

Please let me know if I am clear enough about my expectation.

Kindly flame me with your thoughts.

Comment: What's the question exactly?

Comment: Am I not clear enough in query?? Okay let me brief for your sake :) I wanted to know the API related to new instance launch information ,which I can embed in the shell script .

Comment: I agree with @MarkSetchell. Are you *calling* or *reading* the flat file? Do you want to know both how to write and use the file? What is the menu you mention and how is that relevant?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the AWS command line tools to get the instance launch time:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances
```

You could keep checking the output of this command to get instances launched 'recently'. It's probabaly possible to filter the output using tags so that you can restrict your request to only the instances you're interested in.

Comment: Thanks Daniel!! But I think you missed the point. I want something which can autometically add the new instances to the flat file..which is used by shell script to store the server name : Public ip formation.So next time they visit the menu..that new instances get enlisted there.

Comment: I don't think there's anything like that - you'd have to write it yourself using the command I provided.